# WebSocket Read Sampler doesn't capture the message

Tags: websocket, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I was doing some load testing against a WebSocket to measure the message latency between a publisher (presenter) and subscriber (participant). Below is the structure of my test plan. The "Setup" TG is a **setUp thread group** to make sure that both publisher and subscriber are connected to the WebSocket before starting the communication to measure the latency.

[image]

I had a JSR223 PostProcessor to cache the connection for publisher and subscriber accordingly so that they can pick up the same connection in the following thread groups. 3 messages were sent out from the publisher correctly. However, not sure why the read sampler in the subscriber (ParticipantA) Thread Group did not capture any message even after I increased the timeout to 20s.

[image]

Here is the JSR223 PostProcessor for caching the connection:

```
def participantAConnection = sampler.threadLocalCachedConnection
props.put('participantAConnection' + ctx.getThreadNum(), participantAConnection.get())
```

Here is the JSR223 PreProcessor for restoring the connection in the Participant Thread Group.

```
def participantAConnection = props.get('participantAConnection' + ctx.getThreadNum())
sampler.threadLocalCachedConnection.set(participantAConnection)
```

I can see the properties for the cached connection for the presenter and participant in the debug sampler.

```
participantAConnection0=eu.luminis.websocket.WebSocketClient@1b510239
presenterConnection0=eu.luminis.websocket.WebSocketClient@755f44c9
```

The debug log was enabled below:

```
2022-07-13 01:06:49,666 DEBUG e.l.j.w.SingleReadWebSocketSampler: I/O Error in sampler 'participantACommandsRead'.
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:280) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:306) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:347) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:800) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1455) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1059) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:244) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:263) ~[?:?]
    at eu.luminis.websocket.Frame.parseFrame(Frame.java:61) ~[jmeter-websocket-samplers-1.2.8.jar:?]
    at eu.luminis.websocket.WebSocketClient.receiveFrame(WebSocketClient.java:420) ~[jmeter-websocket-samplers-1.2.8.jar:?]
    at eu.luminis.jmeter.wssampler.WebsocketSampler.readFrame(WebsocketSampler.java:306) ~[jmeter-websocket-samplers-1.2.8.jar:?]
    at eu.luminis.jmeter.wssampler.SingleReadWebSocketSampler.readFrame(SingleReadWebSocketSampler.java:83) ~[jmeter-websocket-samplers-1.2.8.jar:?]
    at eu.luminis.jmeter.wssampler.SingleReadWebSocketSampler.doSample(SingleReadWebSocketSampler.java:71) ~[jmeter-websocket-samplers-1.2.8.jar:?]
    at eu.luminis.jmeter.wssampler.WebsocketSampler.sample(WebsocketSampler.java:169) ~[jmeter-websocket-samplers-1.2.8.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems to be okayish, the question why you're getting timeouts is different.

1. Try to put publisher and subscriber samplers into a single [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and see if this works for you
2. If it does most probably there is an errors somewhere, but we cannot state where without seeing your full test plan, full code or at least [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file with [debug logging enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for (at least) WebSocket Samplers. This line needs to be added to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="eu.luminis" level="debug" />
   ```

Comment: 1. It still didn't work with publisher and subscriber samplers in a single Thread Group. And I actually needed to have them be in different thread groups so that they all run concurrently by marking the test plan to NOT run thread groups consecutively so that the subscribers are listening at the same time the presenters are sending messages to get the accurate latency. 
2. I enabled the debug in the log and add the error to my question above. but looks like it didn't provide me much more insight.

Comment: And I didn't see an error/exception other than the I/O error in read sampler in the JMeter log.